# TPlaySound component Lazarus doesn't play sounds under Ubuntu and crashes in debug mode

Tags: ubuntu, audio, lazarus

I have compiled and installed component from CCR 'playsoundpackage'. I picked demo project from component's folder and compile it.
It works wonderful under Windows, but under Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit in Lazarus (1.4.4, FPC 2.6.4) in debug mode I have an error:

> Project PlaySound component demo raised exception class 'EProcess' with message:
> Cannot execute empty command-line
>
> At address 819FD07

Highlighted: playsound1.Execute;

Compiled demo project under Ubuntu doesn't crash and doesn't play any sounds.
It appears I have a pulseaudio (daemon running and Ubuntu plays any music and sounds well from DE and any other multimedia programms).
Is there something I missed?

Comment: Since there are many frameworks for playing sound in linux, you'll have to detect the correct deamon in your code or find a generic way. You can see here some examples: http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=5215.0 and here http://wiki.freepascal.org/Play_Sound_Multiplatform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the current version, I fixed a couple of bugs recently.